# Wordpress Body Class not implementing

Tags: php, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm trying to create templates for the wordpress theme Flexform. I've created a page as well as a specific header for that page. I didn't need to add a body_class call as it already exists:

```
<body <?php body_class($page_class . ' ' . $is_responsive . ' ' . $extra_page_class); ?>>
```

I checked the classes that were output on the page and found:

```
<body class="page page-id-5538 page-template page-template-beach-php logged-in admin-bar page-shadow responsive-fluid  customize-support" style="">
```

I am using the page-template-beach-php to style on, so that all pages with this template applied will have the same styles. The problem is that I can't get anything to actually apply to the page. I have tried the following options, but nothing shows up, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Option 1 tried

```
.page-template-beach-php #top-bar {
background: #702c91 !important;
background-color: #702c91 !important; }
```

Option 2 tried

```
body.page-template-beach-php #top-bar {
background: #702c91 !important;
background-color: #702c91 !important; }
```

Option 3 tried

```
body .page-template-beach-php #top-bar {
background: #702c91 !important;
background-color: #702c91 !important; }
```

Option 4 tried

```
.page-template-beach-php < #top-bar {
background: #702c91 !important;
background-color: #702c91 !important; }
```

At the moment, I can't even get it to show up on google inspect as an over-written style.

Comment: Sounds like your CSS file may not be included properly. Also, don't pepper your CSS with `important` statements. `important` should be used as a last resort. Please provide a link.

Comment: Link is below in a comment reply to StewD. It's a wordpress theme that I didn't make, but all the other css is calling properly, so I'm not sure exactly how this should be different.

Comment: Also, the '!important' statements in there are because of restraints on the site. I'm trying to style another pre-existing site to match a  different company, we still need all the old CSS for the first company and layout. I was trying to avoid the use of '!important' by styling off a specific class for this page, but it's not working so I tried it as a last resort, and it's obviously still not working, so I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 should work fine assuming there is an element with the id of `top-bar` in the DOM.

Can you provide a URL to take a look?

Comment: I resorted at the moment to directly editing the template, which is not my ideal solution, but it gets the job done temporarily.
Here's the link, it's password protected as I don't really want it public yet.

PW: stackoverflow

http://www.newsoundhearing.com/beach-landing-page/

Answer (score 0):

I added:

`.page-template-beach-php #top-bar {
    background: red;
}`

to line 1421 of your styles.css and it seemed to take affect.

Comment: I can get it to take effect on google's inspect element view, but it doesn't work when I use it in the actual CSS file. I'm not sure why. Maybe something is being called improperly.

Comment: Are you using the stylesheet located here?: http://1g6wmq3ann0z3evtl41ilmvo5h.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/flexform-child/style.css

Comment: Hmmm, when I add that style above in to the stylesheet it worked ok. It is being served from a CDN so you might be getting some caching, best to try in a Chrome Incognito window, or select the disable cache option from Inspector settings and try again.